# How Can I implement a TextBox that displays FullName when not Focused and Splits the name into FirstName, MiddleName and LastName when Clicked WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

In My WPF C# application I created a TextBox that shows the names of a Customer. The names Consists of FirstName, MiddleName and LastName. What I wanted to Implement is that the TextBox to Show FullName (which is the the 3 names joined together, separated by space) when it doesn’t have a Keyboard Focus and to show the 3 names in 3 different textboxes inside the Fullname TextBox when the FullName TextBox gets Keyboard Focus.
I tried my best and Implemented the Control but what I was unable to implement was to get the data and also save the data changes.

Here is my DATABASE SCRIPT:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Customers]    Script Date: 12/7/2023 7:57:47 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([ID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName]) VALUES (1, N'Dees', N'Niis', N'Muus')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([ID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName]) VALUES (2, N'Jiis', N'Kiss', N'Juss')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([ID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName]) VALUES (3, N'Nyuus', N'Nyap', N'Kip')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customers] OFF
GO
```

[image]

[And here are the sample codes in github](https://github.com/MeshkaM/MultiTextBoxName)

Comment: You should create a custom control e.g. a  SplitTextBox. There you can control when to which TextBox. Such a SplitTextBox could expose four dependency properties: LeftValue (e.g., for first name), CenterValue (e.g. for middle name), RightValue (e.g. for last name) and Summary (e.g. for full name).

Comment: @BionicCode did you looked at the sample, everything is working nicely as i expected but the control doesn't receive data despite Debugging the datacontext and the Bindings working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to make your sample app work:

1. Bind the model object to the `ContentControl`:

   ```
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MultiTextBox}"
                    materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="FullName"
                    MinWidth="300"
                    MaxWidth="400"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Content="{Binding}"/>
   ```
2. Set the `Mode` of the binding to the `FullName` property to `OneWay`:

   ```
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="dummyTextBox" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Trigger>
   ```
3. Raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `FullName` property in the `OnChange()` method of the `CustomerModel`:

   ```
    private void OnChange()
    {
        _FullName = FirstName + " " + MiddleName + " " + LastName;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
    }
   ```

Comment: i have another question on this sample, can i ask or Post it On a new thread?

Comment: Please start a new thread if you have another question.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the correct `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` with a wrong value. That's why your bindings won't resolve.

The value of `ContentControl.Content` property is the full name:

```xml
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
```

The important part to know is that the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` is inherited from the `Window` and is the therefore `CustomerModel` instance.

So far so good. But inside your `ControlTemplate` you overwrite the inherited `DataContext` and set it to the value of the `Content` property. This value is the full name (from `CustomerModel.FullName`):

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MultiTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Grid DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}">
```

To make it work simply don't overwrite the (correct) `DataContext`:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MultiTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">

  <!-- DataContext is inherited from the Window and is the CustomerModel -->
  <Grid>
```

Now your bindings will successfully use the `CustomerModel` as binding source.

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'FullName' of type 'MultiTextBoxName.CustomerModel'.'

Comment: Yes, the property FullName is read-only. I have just checked it. And the backingfield is public... it must be private. If a property is a computed property, it can be read-only. If a property won't change, it can be read-only. But you change the property. It doesn't make sense to make it read-only and modify it via the backing field. Instead,  add a private setter. However, you must define the binding created by the Trigger for the dummyTextBox as OneWay explicitly: `<Setter TargetName="dummyTextBox" Property="Text" Value="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}"/>`